# How do I get VMware Converter to be selective with data?

Tags: physical-to-virtual, vmware-converter

Just testing some virtualization.  Just P2Ving an Exchange server, we want to get the system drive (C:) and the data which lives on another drive (D:) with some other stuff.  How do I get the converter to only bring the one folder over and ignore unnecessary data?  I've tried using subst but it's obviously too superficial because the converter doesn't see the drive.

Any ideas or work arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.  It's designed to virtualize the server as a whole - it's not really file aware past that.  If you don't want those files copied, you can virtualize the server, bring it up, delete the files, then re-convert if you need to shrink the drives as thin-provisioned.

Alternately, hook up a USB drive, move the data you don't want converted, convert the drives you do, and presto.

Comment: I understand that, but was wondering if there were any suggestions to avoid that.  Anything clever that I may not be aware of.  That's all.

Comment: You've got mine - move the files off and/or delete them.  That's really all you can do, unfortunately.

Comment: One small exception is that the converter is smart enough to ignore page files and hibernation files.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tip about vmware conversion](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/convert-use-your-physical-machine-in-vmware-virtualbox-virtual-pc/), after you select source machine and say where to save the file, you will get an OPTIONS screen that lets you exclude drives from the source.

> Once preliminary settings are configured, it presents a local machine explorer to let you choose the folders and drives that are to be included in VMDK file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, that on the PC=HOST to be virtualized were other virtual machines. So VMs on that PC should not be converted. I changed the size of the trash to the size of the files from the virtual machines and deleted them to the trash. vConverter does not convert the trash. I converted the HOST to a VM. After converting I restored the VMs from the trash.

Another way is to convert the whole HOST you want to convert and map the newly created virtual disk as a local drive (i. e. z:). Then delete the files on the virtual drive (z:) you do not want on the drive. After that resize the virtual disk if desired or compress it.